# For loops storing issue

Tags: r

How do i store the following loop result in a single vector, keeping it's order? Obs.: `print()` is there only for reprex purposes.

I've tried with `sapply()` but it reordered the results.

```r
meses = c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun",
          "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez", "total")

colunas = c("orcado", "realizado", "desvio", "desvio%")

nomes = NULL

for (x in meses) {
  print(paste(colunas, x, sep = "_"))
}
#> [1] "orcado_jan"    "realizado_jan" "desvio_jan"    "desvio%_jan"  
#> [1] "orcado_fev"    "realizado_fev" "desvio_fev"    "desvio%_fev"  
#> [1] "orcado_mar"    "realizado_mar" "desvio_mar"    "desvio%_mar"  
#> [1] "orcado_abr"    "realizado_abr" "desvio_abr"    "desvio%_abr"  
#> [1] "orcado_mai"    "realizado_mai" "desvio_mai"    "desvio%_mai"  
#> [1] "orcado_jun"    "realizado_jun" "desvio_jun"    "desvio%_jun"  
#> [1] "orcado_jul"    "realizado_jul" "desvio_jul"    "desvio%_jul"  
#> [1] "orcado_ago"    "realizado_ago" "desvio_ago"    "desvio%_ago"  
#> [1] "orcado_set"    "realizado_set" "desvio_set"    "desvio%_set"  
#> [1] "orcado_out"    "realizado_out" "desvio_out"    "desvio%_out"  
#> [1] "orcado_nov"    "realizado_nov" "desvio_nov"    "desvio%_nov"  
#> [1] "orcado_dez"    "realizado_dez" "desvio_dez"    "desvio%_dez"  
#> [1] "orcado_total"    "realizado_total" "desvio_total"    "desvio%_total"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can create a vector and assign the value instead of `print` i.e. `nm1 <- c(); for(x in meses){ nm1 <- c(nm1, paste(colunas, x, sep="_"))}`

Comment: `outer` might be another option `x <- c(outer(colunas, meses, paste, sep="_")); print(x)`

Comment: @akrun your marked this one as duplicate, but the other is a little messy so i won't delete this one, ok?

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda your original question was related to storing the output and the dupe tag for first one does that.  Second one is based on the accepted answer and there are lots of existing answers for those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question with a lot of possible answers. :-)

E.g. instead of `for` loop you can use [`lapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) and [`unlist()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html) that into a simple vector:

```r
unlist(lapply(meses, function(x) paste(colunas, x, sep = "_")))
#>  [1] "orcado_jan"      "realizado_jan"   "desvio_jan"      "desvio%_jan"    
#>  [5] "orcado_fev"      "realizado_fev"   "desvio_fev"      "desvio%_fev"    
#>  [9] "orcado_mar"      "realizado_mar"   "desvio_mar"      "desvio%_mar"    
#> [13] "orcado_abr"      "realizado_abr"   "desvio_abr"      "desvio%_abr"    
#> [17] "orcado_mai"      "realizado_mai"   "desvio_mai"      "desvio%_mai"    
#> [21] "orcado_jun"      "realizado_jun"   "desvio_jun"      "desvio%_jun"    
#> [25] "orcado_jul"      "realizado_jul"   "desvio_jul"      "desvio%_jul"    
#> [29] "orcado_ago"      "realizado_ago"   "desvio_ago"      "desvio%_ago"    
#> [33] "orcado_set"      "realizado_set"   "desvio_set"      "desvio%_set"    
#> [37] "orcado_out"      "realizado_out"   "desvio_out"      "desvio%_out"    
#> [41] "orcado_nov"      "realizado_nov"   "desvio_nov"      "desvio%_nov"    
#> [45] "orcado_dez"      "realizado_dez"   "desvio_dez"      "desvio%_dez"    
#> [49] "orcado_total"    "realizado_total" "desvio_total"    "desvio%_total"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using `sapply` as to avoid copying the vector multiple times:

```
meses = c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun",
          "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez", "total")

colunas = c("orcado", "realizado", "desvio", "desvio%")


as.vector(sapply(meses,function(x) paste(colunas,x,sep="_")))

 [1] "orcado_jan"      "realizado_jan"   "desvio_jan"      "desvio%_jan"     "orcado_fev"      "realizado_fev"   "desvio_fev"      "desvio%_fev"    
 [9] "orcado_mar"      "realizado_mar"   "desvio_mar"      "desvio%_mar"     "orcado_abr"      "realizado_abr"   "desvio_abr"      "desvio%_abr"    
[17] "orcado_mai"      "realizado_mai"   "desvio_mai"      "desvio%_mai"     "orcado_jun"      "realizado_jun"   "desvio_jun"      "desvio%_jun"    
[25] "orcado_jul"      "realizado_jul"   "desvio_jul"      "desvio%_jul"     "orcado_ago"      "realizado_ago"   "desvio_ago"      "desvio%_ago"    
[33] "orcado_set"      "realizado_set"   "desvio_set"      "desvio%_set"     "orcado_out"      "realizado_out"   "desvio_out"      "desvio%_out"    
[41] "orcado_nov"      "realizado_nov"   "desvio_nov"      "desvio%_nov"     "orcado_dez"      "realizado_dez"   "desvio_dez"      "desvio%_dez"    
[49] "orcado_total"    "realizado_total" "desvio_total"    "desvio%_total"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
results <- c()
for(x in meses){
+     results <- c(results, paste(colunas, x, sep = "_"))
+ }
> results
 [1] "orcado_jan"      "realizado_jan"   "desvio_jan"      "desvio%_jan"     "orcado_fev"     
 [6] "realizado_fev"   "desvio_fev"      "desvio%_fev"     "orcado_mar"      "realizado_mar"  
[11] "desvio_mar"      "desvio%_mar"     "orcado_abr"      "realizado_abr"   "desvio_abr"     
[16] "desvio%_abr"     "orcado_mai"      "realizado_mai"   "desvio_mai"      "desvio%_mai"    
[21] "orcado_jun"      "realizado_jun"   "desvio_jun"      "desvio%_jun"     "orcado_jul"     
[26] "realizado_jul"   "desvio_jul"      "desvio%_jul"     "orcado_ago"      "realizado_ago"  
[31] "desvio_ago"      "desvio%_ago"     "orcado_set"      "realizado_set"   "desvio_set"     
[36] "desvio%_set"     "orcado_out"      "realizado_out"   "desvio_out"      "desvio%_out"    
[41] "orcado_nov"      "realizado_nov"   "desvio_nov"      "desvio%_nov"     "orcado_dez"     
[46] "realizado_dez"   "desvio_dez"      "desvio%_dez"     "orcado_total"    "realizado_total"
[51] "desvio_total"    "desvio%_total"
```

The `results <- c(results, paste(colunas, x, sep = "_"))` can be pretty slow, because we are copying whole `results` vector, but in case of small amount of data it should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `nomes` vector:

```
meses = c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun",
          "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez", "total")

colunas = c("orcado", "realizado", "desvio", "desvio%")

nomes = c()

for (x in meses) {
  y <- paste(colunas, x, sep = "_")
  nomes <- c(nomes,y)
}

[1] "orcado_jan"      "realizado_jan"   "desvio_jan"      "desvio%_jan"     "orcado_fev"      "realizado_fev"  
 [7] "desvio_fev"      "desvio%_fev"     "orcado_mar"      "realizado_mar"   "desvio_mar"      "desvio%_mar"    
[13] "orcado_abr"      "realizado_abr"   "desvio_abr"      "desvio%_abr"     "orcado_mai"      "realizado_mai"  
[19] "desvio_mai"      "desvio%_mai"     "orcado_jun"      "realizado_jun"   "desvio_jun"      "desvio%_jun"    
[25] "orcado_jul"      "realizado_jul"   "desvio_jul"      "desvio%_jul"     "orcado_ago"      "realizado_ago"  
[31] "desvio_ago"      "desvio%_ago"     "orcado_set"      "realizado_set"   "desvio_set"      "desvio%_set"    
[37] "orcado_out"      "realizado_out"   "desvio_out"      "desvio%_out"     "orcado_nov"      "realizado_nov"  
[43] "desvio_nov"      "desvio%_nov"     "orcado_dez"      "realizado_dez"   "desvio_dez"      "desvio%_dez"    
[49] "orcado_total"    "realizado_total" "desvio_total"    "desvio%_total"
```